# Increment - Pentaho Data Integration (PDI)

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pdi

I'm starting to use pentaho data integration, and I intend to use it to update a data lake with data from a server. However, I just need to add data that does not yet exist (increment) in the data lake.

Exemple of SQL:

`SELECT COLUM1, COLUM2, COLUM3, COLUM4 FROM TABLEX`

I don't know if I can do this increment via sql, filter or some other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let do it simple:
**Use Stream lookup and filter.**

First step, from source you lookup to target table in lake by some keys(bussiness key, bla bla...) and get new column as name checker (Init checker equal 1 in select clause in lookup link).

Second step, if checker = 1 (Record exist in target) do nothing else insert new record to target.

[image: Simple on mindset]

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to achieve this

Example :

Take two table input steps(source and target) and two add a checksum step, then compare the checksum from source and target, if it does not match insert into target.

Comment: sorry for the delay. Doubt, what option do I use to do this? I tried to use "table compare", but I couldn't.

Comment: for comparing checksum values you have to use lookup steps(stream lookup).